# Facility to allow user view the job in Window Explorer folder

Tags: visual-c++, explorer, windows-shell

I am developing a CAD software using C++/CLI .Net framework 3.5. The files are saved using serializing the objects. How do I provide facility to allow user view the jobs in Window Explorer folder (Like done by AutoCad), where by user gets a chance to look inside the file in explorer itself without opening the file in the software.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show thumbnails or something?

Comment: bdonlan:yes, thumbnails on windows explorer as user selects

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a preview handler. This [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940374.aspx) shows how to build one. But this requires Windows XP or newer OS.

Comment: Marius: Yes, we are using Windows XP and later OS only